# discord.py slash commands not showing

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to create slash commands using discord.py but they do not show up when using discord.

I have tried re inviting the bot with applications.commands and giving the bot admin.

The code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import random
#sorry, global variable
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    print("-"*16)

game = discord.Game("Discord")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(str(arg))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@bot.command()` makes message commands, not slash commands. You won't see any slash commands if you don't make any...

There's an [official example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py) for slash commands that you could look at.

Also, you have both a Client and a Bot. That doesn't make any sense, you can only have one. Choose one, get rid of the other.

Next, your message command `test` is registered to your Bot, but you're running the Client.

Lastly, you're not passing intents. Make sure you're on the most recent version of dpy.